# Assign field values (double) based on values of other field (string) using field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I want to assign numbers to a field, WScore (double), based on field values of Soils (string). They are in the same table of a raster. I'm not trying to add text to a double. What I want to do is this: 
Where Soils = Ds, Oo, Mu, P, or Se,  WScore = 2.5.

I have little python experience so any guidance would be really helpful. Here's what I've come up with so far.

```
Expression: 

WScore=Reclass(!SOILS!)
```

---

```
def Reclass(Soils):

    x=1
    if (Soils == "Ds"):
        x=2.5
    elif (Soils == "Oo"):
        x = 2.5
    elif (Soils == "Mu"):
        x = 2.5
    elif (Soils == "P"):
        x = 2.5
    elif (Soils == "Se"):
        x = 2.5
```

I'm getting error 000539, which I'm guessing is because I can't concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects, though this error # covers many.

Comment: It's hard to say because the code block did not get formatted correctly, but is everything starting with x=1 indented one more tab? It should be. Also, this function never returns anything (e.g. return x). Finally, I don't see any concatenating going on.

Comment: `if Soils in ['Ds','Oo','Mu','P','Se']: return 2.5` is a bit terser given you assign the same numerical value to these.

Comment: I think the code block is formatted correctly now, but x=1 was indented in line with the if statement on the next line. I'll remember the extra tab next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this example, the "soils" field is text and the "WScore" field is double.  The following approach should work for you:

Pre-logic Script Code:

```
def reclass(x):
  if x in ["Ds", "Oo", "Mu", "P", "Se"]:
    return 2.5
  else:
    return 0
```

---

```
reclass(!soils!)
```

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: One more question - If I wanted the remaining values of WScore = 0 (there are a lot), is there an "all but Ds, Oo, Mu, P, Se" way to write this without listing all the other values in the Soils field?

Comment: All you would need to do that would be to add another line under the `if` statement: `else: return 0`.  I edited the answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

following on phloem's comment - it appears you are almost there, you just need a few more pieces:

The following assumes you have the Field Calculator parser set to Python. I've always indented one space for Field Calculator Pre-Logic Script Code following ESRI documentation which I can't seem to locate at this time; it's counter-intuitive to most all other python (indent is 4 spaces) but it works in field calculator.

```
out = 0.0
def Reclass(Soils):
 global out
 if (Soils == "Ds"):
  out = 2.5
 elif (Soils == "Oo"):
  out = 2.5
 elif (Soils == "Mu"):
  out = 2.5
 elif (Soils == "P"):
  out = 2.5
 elif (Soils == "Se"):
  out = 2.5
 return out
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Aaron's method (above) worked, but I'll have other calculations to do where the return values aren't all the same, so this will probably help a lot for that. Thank you!